# How to get localized unit name of a MeasureUnit?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, icu

I know how to get a localized formatted string of a measure value. For example to get "10 meters" I would use

```
val formatter = MeasureFormat.getInstance(ULocale.getDefault(), MeasureFormat.FormatWidth.WIDE)
val text = formatter.format(Measure(10, MeasureUnit.METER))
```

But when I need only the unit name, i.e. "meter", how to get it?
I currently did it by manipulating the string:

```
formatter.format(Measure(1, measureUnit))
                 .replace("1", "")
                 .replace(" ", "")
```

But languages have very different ways to express "1 meter". I am looking for a robust way to do it.